# Eigenvalue Decomposition Issue in Python Numpy

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, python

I am having some issues with Python's Numpy.linalg package.

```
Eigenvalue decomposition:
Given X, find the eigen values (e_val) and the eigen vectors (e_vector), such that:

X * e_val = e_val * e_vector
```

I am using **np.linalg.eigh**, the documentation says it works for real symmetric matrixes.

**Part 1**: An example where numpy.linalg **works fine** (left-hand side equals right-hand side)

Code:

```
X = [[ 0.625, -0.125],
     [-0.125, -0.125]]
e_vals, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(X)
print('eigen values: \n', e_vals)
print('eigen vectors:\n', e_vectors)
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[0]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[0], e_vectors[0]))
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[1]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[1], e_vectors[1]))
```

Output:

```
eigen values: 
 [-0.14528471  0.64528471]
eigen vectors:
 [[-0.16018224 -0.98708746]
 [-0.98708746  0.16018224]]
...
left:  [0.02327203 0.14340871]
right: [0.02327203 0.14340871]
...
left:  [-0.63695244  0.10336315]
right: [-0.63695244  0.10336315]
```

**Part 2**: An example where numpy.linalg **doesn't works** (left-hand side **not** equals right-hand side)

Code:

```
X = [[-0.125, -0.375],
     [-0.375, -0.375]]
e_vals, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(X)
print('eigen values: \n', e_vals)
print('eigen vectors:\n', e_vectors)
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[0]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[0], e_vectors[0]))
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[1]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[1], e_vectors[1]))
```

Output:

```
eigen values: 
 [-0.64528471  0.14528471]
eigen vectors:
 [[ 0.58471028 -0.81124219]
 [ 0.81124219  0.58471028]]
...
left:  [0.23112703 0.08494946]
right: [-0.37730461  0.52348218]
...
left:  [-0.32067163 -0.52348218]
right: [0.11786108 0.08494946]
```

The whole code is on [My GitHub](https://github.com/caitaozhan/testing/blob/master/linalg/eigenval-decomposition.ipynb)

So for some matrix X works, but for others doesn't.

Why? Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvectors are the columns of `e_vectors` but you are selecting the rows instead. Replacing `e_vectors[0]` with `e_vectors[:, 0]` will fix your problem. This was not a problem in your first example because your matrix of eigenvectors was symmetric by coincidence.

```
X = [[-0.125, -0.375],
     [-0.375, -0.375]]
e_vals, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(X)
print('eigen values: \n', e_vals)
print('eigen vectors:\n', e_vectors)
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[:, 0]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[0], e_vectors[:, 0]))
print('...')
print('left: ', np.dot(X, e_vectors[:, 1]))
print('right:', np.dot(e_vals[1], e_vectors[:, 1]))
```

```
eigen values: 
 [-0.64528471  0.14528471]
eigen vectors:
 [[ 0.58471028 -0.81124219]
 [ 0.81124219  0.58471028]]
...
left:  [-0.37730461 -0.52348218]
right: [-0.37730461 -0.52348218]
...
left:  [-0.11786108  0.08494946]
right: [-0.11786108  0.08494946]
```

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html#numpy.linalg.eigh) is: The **column v[:, i]** is the normalized eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]. Will return a matrix object if a is a matrix object.